# Javascript with Selenium WebDriver: "Can't find variable: $"

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

I aimed to use Selenium Webdriver to click a button in a web page. I did it successfully on Chrome Developer Tools but I got "can't find variable" error while I was execute Javascript code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("$('.XbuttonName').click();");
```

I thought it is related with permissions because I also click the button in a healthy way with WebDriver as follows:

```
var button = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("XclassName"));
button.Click();
```

Are there any different options to execute scripts with Selenium Driver?

Comment: You are executing HTML and not Javascript code. Please read up on the JSE and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the element is independent from the page itself.

I use with java, can you try something like this ?

```
var button = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("XclassName"));
jsE.ExecuteScript('arguments[0].click();',button);
```

Comment: will button variable come instead of "0" in arguments? If you meant that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't imported JQuery, which uses the '$' variable.  See [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2921/webdriver-can-i-inject-a-jquery-script-for-a-page-that-isnt-using-jquery).

Comment: I updated my original script.